# Use quotes in Lauterbach strings

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am trying to autogenerate a file using cmm script for Lauterbach. Here is what I want to show up in the file:
{ "source": "XYZ" }    // quotes included

However I cannot get the cmm script to accept the quotes. Using "\" doesnt work either. Is there a way to handle this in CMM scripts?

Answer (score 2):

In PRACTICE (CMM scripts) double-quotes are escaped with double-quotes.

So this should work:

```
OPEN #1 "myfile.log" /Create
WRITE #1 "{ ""source"": ""XYZ"" }" 
CLOSE #1
```